# Problem with the insertion method of a complete binary tree

Tags: java, tree, binary

I have a problem with the method insert to my complete binary tree

```
public void insert( Equipo equipo){
    this.setRootNode(insertThis(this.getRootNode(), node));
}


private BinaryTreeNode insertThis(BinaryTreeNode root, BinaryTreeNode nodo){
    if(root == null) {
        root = nodo;
    } else {
        if(root.getLeftNode() == null) {
            root.setLeftNode(insertThis(root.getLeftNode(),nodo));
        } else if(root.getRightNode() == null) {
            root.setRightNode(insertThis(root.getRightNode(),nodo));
        } else {
            if(root.getLeftNode().getLeftNode() == null 
                || root.getLeftNode().getRightNode() == null) {
                root.setLeftNode(insertThis(root.getLeftNode(),nodo));
            } else if(root.getRightNode().getLeftNode() == null 
                     || root.getRightNode().getRightNode() == null) {
                root.setRightNode(insertThis(root.getRightNode(),nodo));
            } else {
                insertThis(root.getLeftNode(),nodo);
            }
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

The problem is that after the second level of the binary tree, all the nodes go to the left subtree of the root and  no is a complete binary tree, i need resolve it or if you have another implementation of a complete binary tree it is useful for me!.Thanks

Comment: I need a tree that in principle is complete but that does not self-sustain, that is to say that if I delete any node, it should not be complete again

Comment: I need a tree that in principle is complete but that does not self-sustain, that is to say that if I delete any node, it should not be complete again